# Can't locate collections module for python 3

Tags: python-3.x, collections, module

I'm new to Python 3 and following a tutorial which uses a package called collections. While there is an import statement(import collections)in the program, and the program works without error I am confused. I can't locate the package, and it is not listed as one of the downloadable packages. Is it part of python 2/3, and if so where would I see it listed?

Answer (score 3):

I guess it comes with Python 3. You can see the location of an imported module with `__path__`, like this:

```
>>> import collections
>>> collections.__path__
['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/collections']
```

Here's some relevant Python documentation:

- https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories
- [https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/import.html#**path**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/import.html#__path__)

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot. I had no idea so many packages are now included in the basic distribution. I also did not k ow how to search the internal packages (i.e. Math, collections etc). Thank you